# Question about the 'reduced basis transformation'

Tags: computational-physics, linear-algebra, spin-chains, tensor-network

I' ve been reading the review [Ulrich Schollwöck: The density-matrix renormalization group in the age of
matrix product states](https://sci-hub.mksa.top/10.1016/j.aop.2010.09.012) ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3477))
and encountered with a question about the so called 'reduced basis transformation' on page 125 (journal page number; page 39 in the arXiv preprint). 
To summarize, C is a square matrix with SVD decomposition $C=U^\dagger SV$，$C^\prime$ is another matrix that can be written as
\begin{equation}
C^\prime=P^\dagger
\left [ \begin{matrix}
S& 0&0 \\
0& S &0\\
0&0&S
\end{matrix} \right]Q
\end{equation}
where $P^\dagger P=I$ and $Q^\dagger Q=I$, but $P P^\dagger,QQ^\dagger\neq I$, it is said that the largest singular value of $C^\prime$ is smaller than that of C, because this transformation corresponds to a reduced basis transformation into orthogonal subspaces.
My question is what is reduced basis transformation and how is it related to the singular value.

Comment: @Norbert This question is about linear algebra definitions, not computational physics.

Comment: @KyleKanos The way I read the question it is about understanding one step in the explanation of the DMRG algorithm in a review paper about the DMRG algorithm. People searching for answers on the DMRG algorithm might be searching for this, so tagging it accordingly will help them find it. (One *might* read it as a question about linear algebra definitions, but then my answer is completely off -- I think what the OP wants to know is why the claim made in the review is correct, and this type of relation shows up very specifically in this context.)

Comment: @KyleKanos Otherwise, you might as well argue that a question asking why Metropolis updates preserve detailed balance is not about Monte Carlo methods, but about some arithmetics. -- Similarly, if you think it is about linear algebra and nothing else, the tags "spin-chains" and "tensor-network" ought to be removed as well, and it should be migrated to math.

Comment: @Norbert It's asking about specific terms found in a paper (what is "reduced basis transformation" and "how is it (reduced basis transform) related to SVD"). There's nothing "computational" about definitions. I would expect users to be searching for [tag:renormalization], [tag:tensor-network], [tag:linear-algebra], [tag:quantum-information], [tag:spin-models], etc over comp-phys.

Comment: You also have enough rep to [create a tag](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), it might be more beneficial to create a [tag:dmrg] tag and allow users to filter over that, if that is your concern.

Comment: DMRG (and other computational methods based on tensor networks) are precisely the intersection of "computational-physics" (or "numerical-method", but that's a synonym) and "tensor-network", so I think this way of tagging makes much more sense than creating a new tag for precisely that intersection of two existing tags. (Creating such a new tag *can* make sense, but only if the intersection is big enough.)

Comment: By the way, I don't think that "reduced basis transformation" is standard terminology in linear algebra -- at least, I do *not* know what precisely is meant by that (but I get the general idea of what it is supposed to mean in the given context), and a quick search seems to suggest that for the very best, it is terminology used only/primarily in the context of DMRG (and possibly some other computational methods; it might well be that it stems from the historical origins of DMRG in real-space renormalization group methods).

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $P^\dagger P =I$ means $P$ is an isometry, and the same for $Q$.

Next, note that $\mathrm{max\,eig}(P^\dagger MP)\le \mathrm{max\,eig}(M)$, for any hermitian matrix $M$ and any isometry $P$ (this is a consequence of the variational characterization of the largest eigenvalue, i.e. as the maximum of $\langle \phi\vert M\vert\phi\rangle$).

Let me denote the matrix with the several $S$ in $C'$ by $\hat S$.

Then, we use that the largest singular value of $C'$ squared equals
\begin{align}
\mathrm{max\,eig}(C'^\dagger C') &= \mathrm{max\,eig}(P^\dagger \hat S Q Q^\dagger \hat S P)\\
& \le \mathrm{max\,eig}(\hat S Q Q^\dagger \hat S)\\
& \stackrel{(*)}{\le} \mathrm{max\,eig}(Q^\dagger \hat S^2 Q)\\
&\le \mathrm{max\,eig}(\hat S^2)\ ,
\end{align}
which is precisely the largest singular value of $C$ squared and thus completes the proof.

(Note that in (*), we have used that the non-zero spectrum is cyclic (i.e. $AB$ and $BA$ have the same non-zero spectrum), and thus, $\mathrm{max\,eig}(AB)=\mathrm{max\,eig}(BA)$.)